# Authorize.net accept.js python E0007 - User authentication failed due to invalid authentication values

Tags: python, authorize.net, accept.js

Authorize.net

I have a sandbox environment setup and it is working as expected.  I am in the process of migrating to the live system, and started with the example code and my own form.  The production system is not accepting the authentication credentials.

I did not change the code.  I changed from the test credentials to the live credentials through a config file.  I’ve changed the transaction key a time or two and received the same results.  I am not aware of a way to change the API login ID.

config.py:

```
    # Authorize.net test credentials
    AUTHORIZENET_JAVASCRIPT_URL = "https://jstest.authorize.net/v1/Accept.js"
    API_LOGIN_ID = "9..."
    PUBLIC_CLIENT_KEY = (
        "7..."
    )
    TRANSACTION_KEY = "6..."

    .
    .
    .

    # Authorize.net production credentials
    AUTHORIZENET_JAVASCRIPT_URL = "https://js.authorize.net/v1/Accept.js"
    API_LOGIN_ID = "8..."
    PUBLIC_CLIENT_KEY = (
        "4..."
    )
    TRANSACTION_KEY = "7..."
```

The card information is captured and the payment is prepared:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ JAVASCRIPT_URL }}" charset="utf-8">
</script>

<div class="container-narrow">
  <div class="panel owl50">
    <div class="justify-center">
      <h1>Payment information</h1>
    </div>
    <form class="owl50" id="paymentForm" method="POST" action="...">
      <input type="hidden" name="dataValue" id="dataValue" />
      <input type="hidden" name="dataDescriptor" id="dataDescriptor" />
      <div class="owl20">
        <div>
          <label for="cardNumber">Card number:</label>
          <input class="form-input" type="text" name="cardNumber" id="cardNumber" placeholder="card number" />
          <p class="text-small text-red" id="cardNumberError"></p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="expMonth">Expiration month:</label>
          <input class="form-input" type="text" name="expMonth" id="expMonth" placeholder="expiration month" />
          <p class="text-small text-red" id="expMonthError"></p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="expYear">Expiration year:</label>
          <input class="form-input" type="text" name="expYear" id="expYear" placeholder="expiration year" />
          <p class="text-small text-red" id="expYearError"></p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="cardCode">CVV code:</label>
          <input class="form-input" type="text" name="cardCode" id="cardCode" placeholder="cvv code" />
          <p class="text-small text-red" id="cardCodeError"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p class="text-red justify-center" id="dataEntryError"></p>
      <div class="owl20">
        <button class="button button-wide button-green" type="button" onclick="sendPaymentDataToAnet()" />
        Make the payment
        </button>
        <!-- <input class="button button-wide button-yellow" type="submit" name="submit" value="Cancel" /> -->
        <a class="button button-wide button-yellow" href="/members/cart">Cancel</a>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  function sendPaymentDataToAnet() {
    // clear the error messages
    document.getElementById("cardNumberError").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("expMonthError").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("expYearError").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("cardCodeError").innerHTML = "";

    var authData = {};
    authData.clientKey = "{{ PUBLIC_CLIENT_KEY }}";
    authData.apiLoginID = "{{ API_LOGIN_ID }}";

    var cardData = {};
    // cardData.cardNumber = document.getElementById("cardNumber").value;
    // strip blanks from the card number
    cardData.cardNumber = document.getElementById("cardNumber").value.split(" ").join("");
    cardData.month = document.getElementById("expMonth").value;
    cardData.year = document.getElementById("expYear").value;
    cardData.cardCode = document.getElementById("cardCode").value;

    var secureData = {};
    secureData.authData = authData;
    secureData.cardData = cardData;

    Accept.dispatchData(secureData, responseHandler);

    function responseHandler(response) {
      cardCode = document.getElementById("cardCode").value;
      // display authorizenet errors and require the CVV
      if (response.messages.resultCode === "Error" ||
        cardCode == "") {
        // set the dataEntryError message for invalid input
        document.getElementById("dataEntryError").innerHTML = "Data entry error.";
        if (cardCode == "") {
          document.getElementById("cardCodeError").innerHTML = "Please provide valid CVV."
        }
        var i = 0;
        while (i < response.messages.message.length) {
          if (response.messages.message[i].code == "E_WC_05") {
            document.getElementById("cardNumberError").innerHTML = response.messages.message[i].text;
          }
          if (response.messages.message[i].code == "E_WC_06") {
            document.getElementById("expMonthError").innerHTML = response.messages.message[i].text;
          }
          if (response.messages.message[i].code == "E_WC_08") {
            document.getElementById("expMonthError").innerHTML = response.messages.message[i].text;
          }
          if (response.messages.message[i].code == "E_WC_07") {
            document.getElementById("expYearError").innerHTML = response.messages.message[i].text;
          }
          if (response.messages.message[i].code == "E_WC_08") {
            document.getElementById("expYearError").innerHTML = response.messages.message[i].text
          }
          if (response.messages.message[i].code == "E_WC_15") {
            document.getElementById("cardCodeError").innerHTML = response.messages.message[i].text;
          }
          console.log(
            response.messages.message[i].code + ": " +
            response.messages.message[i].text
          );
          i = i + 1;
        }
      } else {
        paymentFormUpdate(response.opaqueData);
      }
    }

    function paymentFormUpdate(opaqueData) {
      document.getElementById("dataEntryError").innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById("dataDescriptor").value = opaqueData.dataDescriptor;
      document.getElementById("dataValue").value = opaqueData.dataValue;

      // If using your own form to collect the sensitive data from the customer,
      // blank out the fields before submitting them to your server.
      document.getElementById("cardNumber").value = "";
      document.getElementById("expMonth").value = "";
      document.getElementById("expYear").value = "";
      document.getElementById("cardCode").value = "";

      document.getElementById("paymentForm").submit();
    }
  }
</script>
```

I am setting the SDK environment and credentials based on my environment; development or production:

```
    # Create a merchantAuthenticationType object with authentication details
    merchantAuth = apicontractsv1.merchantAuthenticationType()
    merchantAuth.name = app.config["API_LOGIN_ID"]
    merchantAuth.transactionKey = app.config["TRANSACTION_KEY"]
    print(app.config["JAVASCRIPT_URL"])
    print("API login ID: ", app.config["API_LOGIN_ID"])
    print("Transaction key: ", app.config["TRANSACTION_KEY"])

    .
    .
    .

    # Create the controller and get response
    createtransactioncontroller = createTransactionController(createtransactionrequest)
    # For PRODUCTION use
    createtransactioncontroller.setenvironment(
        app.config["AUTHORIZENET_JAVASCRIPT_URL"]
    )
    createtransactioncontroller.execute()
```

From the log using the sandbox credentials:

```
https://jstest.authorize.net/v1/Accept.js
API login ID: 9...
Transaction key: 6...
Successfully created transaction with Transaction ID: ...
Transaction Response Code: 1
Message Code: 1
```

From the log using the production credentials:

```
https://js.authorize.net/v1/Accept.js
API login ID: 8...
Transaction key: 7...
Error Code: E00007
Error Message: User authentication failed due to invalid authentication
```

Comment: You sure you have the correct credentials for production, the error message seems to indicate you don't?

Comment: I agree, and I am confident as I can be.  I've checked the API login ID too many times and I've generated a new transaction key a couple of times and verified it each time.  I haven't found a way to generate a new API login ID.  

The log confirms I'm grabbing the sandbox credentials for testing and the production credentials for the live system.

I've search for solutions and most are solved by generating a new transaction key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could the account being set to Test instead of Live have anything to do with it? There is a toggle somewhere to switch to Live processing from Test.
When logged in, Account > Security Settings > Test Mode
Burke, I overlooked it this morning, the issue is the endpoint you are sending post requests to. Sandbox and production have different endpoints. If you notice the one you are using above is jstest.authorize but the production one is without the "test" part of that. Hope this helps! js.authorize.net/v1/Accept.js Also, if you are using any server side code with their API, that endpoint also changes in a similar fashion. Sandbox API Endpoint: apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api Production API Endpoint: api.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api

Comment: Great question.  I currently have the production site in test mode, which I believe enables me to test the authentication, but not process live payments.  I've also switched the setting to live and received the save authentication error.  This particular setting seems not to effect the outcome.

Comment: Burke, I overlooked it this morning, the issue is the endpoint you are sending post requests to. Sandbox and production have different endpoints. If you notice the one you are using above is jstest.authorize but the production one is without the "test" part of that. Hope this helps!
https://js.authorize.net/v1/Accept.js

Also, if you are using any server side code with their API, that endpoint also changes in a similar fashion. 

Sandbox API Endpoint: https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api

Production API Endpoint: https://api.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api

Comment: Kris, thanks for helping, but I'm not sure I fully understand your message.  I'm using the URL with test for the sandbox, along with the sandbox credentials (above the dotted line).  I'm using the URL without test for production, along with the production credentials (below the dotted line). Relative to the config snippet above, the URL and credentials are loaded based on the environment; the sandbox values are loaded when I'm working locally and the production values are loaded on the server.  These settings are captured in the log snippets, and reflect what I expect to see.

Comment: Apologies, I overlooked that you were setting the endpoint based on environment. Have you tried your credentials in a simple request using postman or something more manual to ensure the credentials are valid for production account? Also, it looks like you are using the python SDK, have you set the environment in that? If not, it will default to sandbox.
createtransactioncontroller.setenvironment(constants.PRODUCTION)

Comment: Kris, I took a step forward thanks to you. I missed the need to set the environment to production; it wasn't in the example code I grabbed. I've update the original post to reflect these changes. I am now receiving a None response. Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: I may be missing it, but I dont see the value for AUTHORIZENET_JAVASCRIPT_URL. Can you confirm this is properly being set to the final value of `https://api2.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api` for production access?

Comment: Sorry.  My code was out of sync with the snippets above.  I am not posting to the site you mentioned; I'm posting to the js.authorize site.  I haven't seen the site your provided within the accept.js documentation.  What am I missing?

Comment: Kris, thanks to you, I believe I am on the correct path.  I was focused on the Accept.js componet and didn't focus on the SDK.  Having the SDK default to the sandbox without something explicit in the code didn't help.  I am explicitly posting to the sandbox at `https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api` and the production site at `https://api2.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api`. Thank you once again.